# Access to Session from AppServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-session

I have to access to the session and get some values and share it with all my views I have used following code on my `AppServiceProvider.php`, but it returns null when I read my session, Following code I have tried

```php
$errors = json_encode(session()->get('errors'));
View::share('validation_errors', $errors);
```

Without sharing if I call the same function and assigned it through controller before view been called it works without any problem.

Comment: Are you calling it after the session is created?

Comment: yea session created in previous controller

Comment: One thing to know the errors of validation is automatically shared with all vies by Laravel for you :)

Comment: @nuz123 Maraboc is right validation messaged are already shared in all views so please explain what are you trying to achive here. 

Ref @ https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

Comment: @Iftikharuddin after validation i redirect to another page in that case errors not came to front end therefore i used session to store the errors and retrieve from front end however it work if i set a variable and retrieve session and passed to the view.